# How to convert this haml snippets to html.erb code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I found this snippet to the web but unfortunately this based on `haml` and my project based on `html.erb` but I need this snippet into my project converted to `html.erb`

```
= div_for(user) do
 = image_tag user.image_url
 = user.name
 .online-indicator{ class: !user.online_now? && 'xs-none' } Online Now!
```

My concept is zero about `haml` syntax, could anyone please suggest me what should be exact syntax with `html.erb`?

I'm really sorry to put this into StackOverflow but I couldn't have any way to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

created by https://haml2erb.org/

```
<%= div_for(user) do %>
  <%= image_tag user.image_url %>
  <%= user.name %>
  <% c = !user.online_now? && 'xs-none' %>
  <div class="<%= c %> online-indicator">Online Now!</div>
<% end %>
```